# Google Play In app billing: What is the URI of a item's page?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

If the user have subscribed something in the app, they might want to open that "subscription", so that he can view, cancel it.
I know how to link to an app: http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/linking.html
Similar to such URI, is there a URI that points to the "subscription page of a specific item in Google Play"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this link:](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html#overview)

> After users have purchase subscriptions, they can view the
>   subscriptions and cancel them from the My Apps screen in the Play
>   Store app or from **the app's product details page** in the Play Store
>   app.

I just link the user to the App's product details page, so that user can cancel his/her subscription.